# social login in woocommerce my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used social login plugin for woocommerce myaccount page, but the plugin providing social login to my wp-admin.this not correct way.
Is there any plugin for only woocommerce social login.
Or how to create custom login form to go my account page in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

There are many addon for WooCommerce Social login. Search on the net and you'll get plenty of options.

Some of the addons are listed below which will help you achieve this is:

- [WooCommerce Social Login](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-social-login/)
- [WooCommerce Social Login - WordPress plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-social-login-wordpress-plugin/8495883)
- [YITH WooCommerce Social Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-social-login/)